# What's a Wholesale ordering solution?

Tags: forms, checkout, shopping-cart, bulk

We have hundreds of products that are purchased in bulk. It would be easiest if a user could go down a list and mark quantities and then submit an order.

There doesn't have to be a checkout, because orders have to be approved before moving forward with payment, and most orders are at least $5,000.

Has anyone heard of solution that can achieve this in EE?

We've tried FreeForm, but we've maxed out the number of fields allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I expect any of the 3 main ecommerce add-ons will suffice, but personally I'd recommend Expresso Store. It has a [multi-product add to basket](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/product_form_tag.html) ability, so you can list out many products, the user can then work down a list you display from entries, add quantities to and then submit (add to basket). Each product would be priced on a single entity/blob, then let Store do the quantity calculations. This will also allow you to utilise a basket, which then opens more options for your design, UX, and project future scope.

You don't have to utilise the payment gateway, just simply use a dummy gateway and setup the email (in Expresso Store) to the client to inform them that their request has been received and an email (again in Store) that gets sent to you with what they have ordered (requested), along with their contact details for you to contact them and fulfill.

If project budget is an issue and you can't stretch to an ecom module, you should be able to still do it via Freeform but not using a field for each product (which sounds like your issue), but consolidate all the products and quantities into a single field via JavaScript and store in Freeform as a [multi-select field](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/docs/default_fieldtypes/#multi-select_attr_name).

Comment: I'm also researching the multi-select functionality on FreeForm, that sounds promising. Thanks for these new avenues!